# Which MySQL database engine is better for storing sessions and session data: MyISAM or InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, session, innodb, myisam

Pretty straightforward question.

I use InnoDB for everything else, for a couple of reasons. Is it a performance hit over MyISAM for a 'high-traffic' table?

Comment: @Charles, MEMORY is a great choice, because it will be waay faster than anything else.  Only issue is that session data won't persist between MySQL restarts.

Comment: @Greg: MEMORY = [MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html) :-)

Comment: @Chris, while that is true, MySQL restarts shouldn't occur in production.

Comment: You also need to define 'high-traffic'. I've seen a website with over 6000 active sessions in a MyISAM table and not break a sweat.

Comment: @Charles, Mike -- thank you! I hadn't even considered that. @staticsan: Afraid I can't put a number on it at this time.

Comment: @Charles Restarts occur pretty much everywhere.  How do you deal with configuration changes, and those wonderful times when someone trips over the cord?

Comment: @Chris, a fair point.  However, at that point the entire site is likely to go down, so losing only session data is likely to be the least of our cares.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're looking at a pretty even mix of read/write traffic, InnoDB is the better choice.  MyISAM's full-table locks on every write would probably be murder.  MyISAM fairs better with 90%+ read or 90%+ write situations.

I believe that's mentioned in [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067)